# ASP.NET - Doesnt databind work in asp repeater itemtemplate without full page refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, google-maps, updatepanel

I'm testing a simple code in asp.net with google maps and markers, i want to update the markers based on the button chosen.
I'm trying to bind the value(datatable) from a stored procedure to a repeater itemtemplate and do a partial refresh in the map, it's working in the first page load(the bind), but the new value(when the button is pressed) doesn't bind at all.

UpdatePanel

```
                                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
                                      <ContentTemplate>

                                <p>

                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" class="btn btn-outline btn-link" AutoPostback=true Text="1"   onClick=" Button1"  />

                                    |

                               <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"  Text="2" class="btn btn-outline btn-link" AutoPostback=true OnClick =" Button_2" />
                                    |

                                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" class="btn btn-outline btn-link" Text="3" AutoPostback=true  onClick=" Button3" />                                

                                </p>


                                     </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Template

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
     var markers = [
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
            {
            "title": '<%# Eval("Title") %>',
            "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
            "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
            }
</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
    ,
</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
];
```

Map

```
window.onload = function () {
        LoadMap();
    };
    var myLatlng;
    var markerCluster;
            //On UpdatePanel Refresh
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {  
                CreateMarkers();  
                alert("markers"+JSON.stringify(markers, null, 4));


            }
        });
    };


 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.45, -49.25);;
        var opcoes = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        function LoadMap() {                            
             mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), opcoes);
            CreateMarkers();
        }

        function CreateMarkers() {
        var googleMarkers = []; 
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            markersaux = markers;
        for (i = 0; i < markersaux.length; i++) {            
            var data = markersaux[i]                       
            if (data.lat == null || data.lat == "" || data.lat == "undefined" || data.lat == "null") {
                 myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.438 , -49.2787);
            } else {
                var latitude = data.lat.replace(",", ".");
                var longitude = data.lng.replace(",", ".");

                 myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            }
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: mapa,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    title: data.title
            });
            googleMarkers.push(marker);

            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent("Title: " + data.title +"<br /> Latitude: " + data.lat + "<br />Longitude: " + data.lng);
                    infoWindow.open(mapa, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);           
    }
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    DataTable dt = this.GetData(sql);

    rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
    rptMarkers.DataBind();//It's binding here


    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {

    }

}




protected void Button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    DataTable dt = this.GetData(sql2);
    this.rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
    this.rptMarkers.DataBind();//Value of dt here is correct, but it's not binding

    this.UpdatePanel1.Update();

}
```

Comment: I noticed in your `For` statement that you have initialized the variable `i` but I don't see any declaration of it. Is this deliberate? Do you have global variable `i` somewhere?

Comment: i'm only using it to separate objects present in the markers template